# can I configure a different theme per category in a BlogEngine.net blog?

Tags: c#, asp.net, blogengine.net

My scenario is this:

The client wants one blog with several categories configured to represent different departments.

When you are browsing each category the header graphic should be different colours patterns etc to represent each department.

I am happy to do this by injecting some CSS or by maintaining multiple themes; whichever is possible.

I did try to search for this but terms like "blogengine.net theme per category" didn't work for me, the technical terms are too vague for it to cut through general theme or category discussion.

I appreciate any advice you can give me!

Answer (score 0):

I've just  finished a similar customization. By recompiling the BlogEngine source code, you can add columns to the database. I added a background color for each category and use eyecon.ro's ColorPicker to select.